# ¿Cómo puedo ajustar un tiempo a un vídeo en HTML?

Tags: html

¿Cómo puedo editar con algún atributo o Javascript los valores de los tiempos del vídeo? Por ejemplo, que en vez de aparecer el número 0:08, el número sea 0:10 pero que el poster no cambie

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "el poster"? ¿Puedes poner algo de lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

http://lineadecodigo.com/html5/tiempo-total-de-un-video-html5/

puedes mirarlo te voy a ser un resumen.

Cuando cargamos un vídeo en HTML5 puede ser interesante el conocer el tiempo total de la duración del vídeo. El elemento HTMLMediaElement nos permite consultar esta información.

Para poder consultar el tiempo total de un vídeo utilizaremos el atributo duration del HTMLMediaElement.

```
var v = document.getElementById("mivideo");
document.write(v.duration);
```

Ahora, que cuando ejecutemos este código nos llevaremos una sorpresa y es que, el atributo duration, no nos devolverá ningún valor. Esto es debido a que la información del tiempo total de un vídeo no es cargada hasta que tenemos la información de los metadatos del vídeo.

Y, ¿cuándo tenemos los metadatos del vídeo? Para ello tenemos el evento loadeddata. Así que tendremos que poner un listener sobre dicho evento en el elemento video. En este caso utilizaremos el método .addEventListener() para llevar a cabo dicha tarea.

```
var v = document.getElementById("mivideo");
v.addEventListener("loadeddata",function(ev){
   ...
},true);
```

Será dentro del listener dónde codifiquemos el acceso al campo duration del HTMLMediaElement para obtener el tiempo total de un vídeo HTML5.

```
var v = document.getElementById("mivideo");
v.addEventListener("loadeddata",function(ev){
   document.getElementById("tiempototal").innerHTML = v.duration;       
},true);
```

Tiempototal es una capa de nuestra página HTML5 sobre la que volcaremos el resultado.